# How can I work out why a transaction isn't being included in any blocks?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multi-signature, testnet, python, transaction-verification

I've crafted a testnet p2sh address using `python-bitcoinlib`.

The script contents is 2-of-2 multisig: `2, key1, key2, 2, OP_CHECKMULTISIG`

Redeem script:

```
522102e637c8658a9647e67b3d9961f0e0a6d1af9427396db430bfef9e2e01bb5618d12103e645fe283cc6759cb0b5aae4a767f74195fa3deeee69749345b5e4b5f3aae7d852ae
```

Address:
`2N1TtyXGR2kDpnaGkJNx17fPyURqgLDdEgd`

I then generated and signed a transaction spending some funds. I used `python-bitcoinlib`'s `VerifyScript` to check the transaction and no exceptions were raised.

Transaction:

```
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
```

It's been over 10 hours and the transaction [hasn't been included in any blocks](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/49f314ee9a31633688637abc9712a62e6222a659afad9b91db25ac16894a6958/).

Is there some way to work out why that might be, or if there is something wrong with the transaction?

Comment: I can't find your transaction on any of the blockchain explorers, so I assume that it was either non-standard and wasn't propagated, or the fee was below minRelayTxFee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction needs a fee.

I mistakenly thought that testnet transactions didn't require fees, but the requirements are just lower. Given that this is spending a recent output and the amount is very small, it is being ignored.
[Do testnet networks require the same main network fee?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/do-testnet-networks-require-the-same-main-network-fee)

A transaction including a fee went through successfully: https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/0119445bfc577bcd032a079b03d1534be91b01e789874a02f88b9234ab72429d/